# Converting a weird data type to Str

Tags: python, type-conversion, python-twitter

I apologize in advance as I am not sure how to ask this! Okay so I am attempting to use a twitter API within Python. Here is the snippet of code giving me issues:

```
trends = twitter.Api.GetTrendsCurrent(api)
print str(trends)
```

This returns:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I attempt to .encode, the interpreter tells me I cannot encode a Trend object. How do I get around this?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? How 'bout just `print trends`?

Comment: When I try to 'print trends' I get a similar error as above! UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-5: ordinal not in range(128) This is within python 2.7

Comment: Can you change your encoding from UTC-8 to Unicode?  I suspect that you have a non-standard character in there.

Comment: @Prune do you mean using .encode?

Comment: That's one way.  There are also compiler directives to specify Unicode for the entire run, so you don't have to encode every character that doesn't fit the ASCII model.

Comment: .encode does not work as the data type is Trend not string, but I will try the compiler way and let you know


Edit: Any idea how to do that in PyCharm? I am new!

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple answer:

Use `repr`, not `str`. It should always, always work (unless the API itself is broken and that is where the error is being thrown from).

#### Long answer:

By default, when you cast a Unicode string to a byte str (and vice versa) in Python 2, it will use the `ascii` encoding by default for the conversion process. This works most of the time, but not always. Thus, nasty edge cases like this are a pain. One of the big reasons for the break in backwards compatibility in Python 3 was to change this behavior.

Use `latin1` for testing. It may not be the correct encoding, but it will always (always, always, always) work and give you a jumping off point for debugging this properly so you at least can print something.

```
trends = twitter.Api.GetTrendsCurrent(api)
print type(trends)
print unicode(trends)
print unicode(trends).encode('latin1')
```

Or, better yet, when encoding force it to ignore or replace errors:

```
trends = twitter.Api.GetTrendsCurrent(api)
print type(trends)
print unicode(trends)
print unicode(trends).encode('utf8', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

Chances are, since you are dealing with a web based API, you are dealing with UTF-8 data anyway; it is pretty much the default encoding across the board on the web.

Comment: ThePentium's answer above worked. My IDE was not using the correct encoding format. Thank you for your tips though!